# Factor to numeric conversion via %>%: unexpected results

Tags: r, dplyr, type-conversion, magrittr

When converting a factor into numeric vector via the pipe %>% operator, I have wrongly assumed that

myfactor %>% as.character %>% as.numeric

would give the same result as

myfactor %>% as.numeric(as.character(.))

```
c(0,1,2) %>% as.factor  %>% as.character %>% as.numeric ## returns 0,1,2
c(0,1,2) %>% as.numeric(as.character(as.factor(.)))     ## returns 0,1,2
c(0,1,2) %>% as.factor  %>% as.numeric(as.character(.)) ## returns 1,2,3 (unexpected)
myfun <- function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))
c(0,1,2) %>% as.factor  %>% myfun                       ## returns 0,1,2
```

Could someone kindly explain the discrepant results? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe operator passes the piped object as first argument of the following function. The dot only changes this behavior when it is in the same function call, this is explained in the [documentation](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html) in the details section.

So your third line is equivalent to

```
as.numeric(as.factor(c(0,1,2)), as.character(as.factor(c(0,1,2))))
```

while to get the expected result you would need

```
c(0,1,2) %>% as.factor %>% { as.numeric(as.character(.)) }
```

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to this behavior of the dot when it is placed within nested functions. I should have read the documentation more carefully! Just a question for my own understanding: would you say that line 2 seems to "work" only because it is equivalent to `as.numeric(c(0,1,2), as.character(as.factor(c(0,1,2))))`?

Comment: Yes, there you get the same result just by chance!